# Cargar datos de tabla Mysql hace que el combobox no se visualice

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

> El problema

Al cargar los datos al combobox este los carga pero el recuadro no se visualiza.

Asi se deberia ver
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al correr la aplicacion se ve asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si clickeo en el lugar donde deberia estar el combobox pasa esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Codigos

Tengo una funcion que carga todos los items de una columna en un combobox.

> Funcion (A)

```
   Function MySQL_DataRead_VariacionCombobox(_Comboboxallenar As ComboBox, _Tabla As String, _Rangos As String)
        _MSQLDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT " & _Rangos & " FROM " & _Tabla, _SqlConnection_String_As_MYSQL)
        _MSQLDataTable = New DataTable

        Try

            _MSQLDataAdapter.Fill(_MSQLDataTable)

            _Comboboxallenar.DataSource = _MSQLDataTable

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Function
```

Luego tengo otra funcion que dependiendo que item se selecciona son los datos que trae llenando una serie de textboxs

> Funcion (B)

```
    Function MySQL_DataRead(_Rangos As String, _Tabla As String, _SegunCol As String) As DataTable
        _MSQLDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT " & _Rangos & " FROM " & _Tabla & " WHERE Usuario='" & _SegunCol & "'", _SqlConnection_String_As_MYSQL)
        _MSQLDataTable = New DataTable

        Try

            _MSQLDataAdapter.Fill(_MSQLDataTable)

            MySQL_DataRead = _MSQLDataTable


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Function
```

Y para llamarlas hago lo siguiente

> LLamada de funcion (A)

```
 Dim Pilares As Pilares = New Pilares
        Dim _Tabla As String = "Usuarios"
        Dim _Rangos As String = "*"
        Val1.DataSource = Pilares.MySQL_DataRead_VariacionCombobox(Val1, _Tabla, _Rangos)
    Val1.DisplayMember = "Usuario"

Llamada de funcion (B)
   '{[Parte 1]
    Dim Pilares As Pilares = New Pilares
    Dim _Rangos As String = "*"
    Dim _Tabla As String = "CredencialesDeUsuarios"
    Dim _TablaCredenciales As DataTable = Pilares.MySQL_DataRead(_Rangos, _Tabla, Val1.Text)

    val3.Text = _TablaCredenciales.Rows(0)("Nombre").ToString
    val4.Text = _TablaCredenciales.Rows(0)("Horario").ToString
    val5.Text = _TablaCredenciales.Rows(0)("Apellido").ToString
    val6.Text = _TablaCredenciales.Rows(0)("Mail").ToString
    val7.Text = _TablaCredenciales.Rows(0)("Sexo").ToString
    val8.Text = _TablaCredenciales.Rows(0)("Puesto").ToString
    val9.Text = _TablaCredenciales.Rows(0)("FechaDeNacimiento").ToString
    val10.Text = _TablaCredenciales.Rows(0)("Nivel").ToString
    '}


    '{[Parte 2]

    _Tabla = "Usuarios"
    Dim _TablaUsuarios As DataTable = Pilares.MySQL_DataRead(_Rangos, _Tabla, Val1.Text)
    val2.Text = _TablaUsuarios.Rows(0)("Contraseña").ToString

    '}
```

En la llamada de la funcion B uso dos veces la funcion porque tengo datos en 2 tablas distintas que debo recuperar

Mis tablas en MySql se componen de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto es un problema de la vista, porque el control esta (ya que haces click y aparece). Probablemente si moves el form tambien aparece. Proba hacer un refresh del form si ves que sigue pasando.

Comment: Usando Me.Refresh() no me arreglo nada

Comment: Me.Controls.Clear()
InitializeComponent()

Si hago esto después del código el combobox aparece pero sin valores (obviamente), El código que carga el combobox estara entrando en conflicto de alguna manera?

Comment: No deberia. Es algun tipo de control raro o son los controles comunes de net?

Comment: Si si, son los comunes de net

Comment: No se que decirte. solo vi eso con problemas de drivers en PC. Probaste en otra compu a ver que pasa?

Comment: Si pongo un Try....Catch me devuelve este error 

There is no row at position 0 y el combobox aparece pero sin datos dentro y con el desplegable del tamaño como si en algún momento hubiese tenido datos

Comment: si pones un try donde? edita la pregunta y agreas esa informacion

Comment: Perdon estoy con mil cosas, Si pongo un Try en la llamada de la funcion (B) me devuelve ese error y luego no me carga nada, en cambio si se lo saco no me trae errores y me devuelve el combobox asi invisible